# How do I print out from the function?

Tags: python, pynput

I try to write some click-event program using pynput library. I can't find out how to print counter out from the function to use it further.

```
root.counter = 0


def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        root.counter += 1
        logging.info(str(root.counter) + '. Mouse clicked at ({0}, {1}) with {2}'.
                     format(x, y, button))
        print('Button clicked: ' + str(root.counter))

        if not pressed:
            # Stop listener
            return False

listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
listener.start()
```

Comment: Your if pressed and everything indented underneath it is not indented under your function.

Comment: At same indentation level as both ifs, if you add `return root.counter` ?

Comment: @andreis11 it doesn't work. It just returns 0

Comment: ok, then I would try this: does `print('Button clicked: ' + str(root.counter))` return a value? (next to the Button clicked string) if it does ,add the `return root.counter` at the same identation level with `print(Button..` and under it.